# Fury of Dracula 3rd ed. - Fangs point scoring

Tags: fury-of-dracula

In Fury of Dracula 3rd edition, does Dracula score 1 point **whenever** 'Fangs' combat card is resolved, or only if it was resolved with night & mesmerized conditions met? I know the rules just say *"when 'Fangs' is resolved"*, but the reason I'm asking is because of the way the text on the card is printed out, with no empty line above *"Then, advance the influence track by 1"*:

[image: Fangs combat card]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fantasy Flight clarified this:

> The 1 influence point only occurs when it is night and the engaged hunter is mesmerized.

source: https://boardgamegeek.com/article/21076368#21076368